# Are the "body", "comments" and "answers" parameters supported in the API version 2.x?

Tags: support, api-v2, questions, documentation, parameters

Earlier with version 1.x, the parameters: `body`, `comments` and `answers` etc. were available. But these don't seem to be supported with API version 2.x.
Are these parameters not supported in new API? Are they moved to filters?

Sample URL in V1.x:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/?body=true&comments=true&answers=true&tagged=java

Even if I add these parameters with V2.x methods, body/comments/answers are not in the response. And I get no errors either.

If body and comments have been removed from methods, how can I then include in response?

Answer (score 3):

> Are they moved to filters?

Yes, you need to generate a filter that includes the `question.body`, `question.comments`, and `question.answers` fields. There are [shorthand filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) (i.e. `_bca`) that will do this for upgrade compatibility, but their use is discouraged and you're better off just making a filter that contains exactly what you want anyway.